# Как создать в C# бесконечное создание элементов

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно сделать

1. Чтобы при нажатии кнопки, добавлялись два элемента в панели, 1 элемент кнопка второй textbox,
2. Когда панель с элементами появляется она должна быть в ряду 3x3
3. Кнопки должны появляется бесконечно при клике на кнопку создание панели с элементами

C#, winforms

Comment: Хорошее техзадание, хоть и не до конца ясное, например непонятно, что за "ряду 3х3", и откуда появляется панель. Но самое главное - здесь не выполняют работу на заказ, а помогают вам выполнить ее самостоятельно. Что именно не получается? Покажите код, скриншоты, что там у вас накопилось.

Comment: возможно стоит использовать какую-нибудь stackpanel или подобный контейнер, в который будут умещаться эти элементы. Вы можете создать элемент текст+кнопка в wpf и импортировать его в ваш winforms проект, организовать какой-нибудь метод add для добавления этого элемента по кнопке.

Comment: @Elena_Gnil в винформах тоже есть панели, стекпанель `FlowLayoutPanel` называется. И как импортировать что-либо из wpf в винфррмы я не знаю, поделитесь секретом. Да и зачем. Ведь если разобраться с wpf, тогда винформы нафиг не нужны.